# change css with jquery , doesnt work in FireFox

Tags: jquery

I have a dd element in my html page, class names are generated from database id, and in Java script file I use

```
theHeight=200;
$("dd."+i).css({height: theHeight});
```

this code works good in opera, chrome, IE 8, but doesnt work  in FireFox 12.0 
I need to change height of element in a css , but on a runtime from jquery. what is wrong with it, is there any way to make it work with FireFox

Thanks

Comment: how does the rest of your script look like? what you use to trigger it? show the html and css of the element you want to change the height on

Comment: If the i is a numeric ID, I would try prefixing the class name with a letter, as class names are not allowed to begin with a digit. Firefox 14 seems to be able to handle numeric class names though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting it like this:

```
theHeight=200
$("dd."+i).height(theHeight);
```

Or try appending 'px' to the height value:

```
theHeight=200
$("dd."+i).css({height: theHeight + 'px'});
```